# Accessing multiple childs returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to access the layout using `@ViewChild`, but when I use it with QueryList it returns undefined.

```
<ng-template let-service="item" backgroundColor="pink">
                    <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" backgroundColor="#26252A">
                        <GridLayout class="item"
                                    [id]="service.name"
                                    #grid
                                    rows="*, *, 2*" columns="100, *, 10" 
                                    >
```

Above is html template part (not complete ofc). And here is the typescript:

```
@ViewChild('grid') grids: QueryList<ElementRef>;

add(){
   console.log("grid " + this.grids.last.nativeElement.id);
}
```

So this returns : `"ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.grids.last.nativeElement')"`

Comment: You want `@ViewChildren`. `@ViewChild` is for a single element, not a list.

Comment: Thank you. That worked, but for some reason when I iterate through it it shows the first element as duplicate, so instead of 2 elements, it shows 3